# tests fat jar with maven shade-plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, junit, maven-shade-plugin

I need to build one jar for execution tests during CI process on server. This jar have to contains all test dependencies (like junit, mockito) and spring boot dependencies while my test will use spring. I wrote such maven configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>shade</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-fat</finalName>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                        <shadeTestJar>false</shadeTestJar>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>pl.klolo.demo.demo.smoke.SmokeTestAppKt</mainClass>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Maven built one jar with all dependencies, but when I try to execute test I have strange error which I cannot understand:

```
2022-04-08 20:45:44.611  INFO 591618 --- [           main] p.k.d.demo.tests.DemoApplicationTests    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-04-08 20:45:45.018 ERROR 591618 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class 
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:237) ~[demo-fat.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:208) ~[demo-fat.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.access$000(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:154) ~[demo-fat.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.lambda$getInPriorityOrder$0(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:64) ~[demo-fat.jar:0.0.1]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:62) ~[demo-fat.jar:0.0.1]
```

Could you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

SmokeTestApp:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val launcher = LauncherFactory.create()
    val listener = SummaryGeneratingListener()
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener)
    launcher.execute(
       LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
          .selectors(selectPackage("pl.klolo"))
          .build()
    )

    printSummary(listener.summary)
    exitProcess(
        if (listener.summary.failures.isEmpty()) 0
        else -1
    )
}

fun printSummary(summary: TestExecutionSummary) {
    println("Passed tests:  ${summary.testsSucceededCount}")

    summary.failures.forEach {
        println("###FAILED TEST ${it.testIdentifier.uniqueId}###")
        it.exception.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

DemoApplicationTests:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class DemoApplicationTests(
    @Value("\${test.applicationURI}") val applicationURI: String,
    @Value("\${test.applicationPort}") val applicationPort: Int
) {

init {
    RestAssured.baseURI = applicationURI
    RestAssured.port = applicationPort
}

@Tag("smoke_test")
@Test
fun contextLoads() {
    println("smoke test ===> 1")
}
```

Comment: If you have spring/spring boot application you should not use maven-shade-plugin use the spring-boot-maven-plugin to package your application.

Comment: spring-boot-maven-plugin doesn't give option for creation fat jar with test...

Comment: Because you don't need to create a fat-jar for running tests. That can be done with `@SpringBootTest` annotation to tests part with a number of tests because you already wrote in your post...which I don't understand? What kind of test does not work? What do you like to test?

Comment: I need execute test on remote enviroiment, not local and I don't want to package my source and execute e.g maven on remote server. This tests should execute without access to internet and without compilation from source

Comment: What kind of tests needs to run on a remote environment which can't be run local with appropriate testing support of Spring ..? What kind of test you need to run which is only available remotely?

Comment: smoke test in continous deployment process, when I have to verify if new application version works correctly before redirect user request to new instance. I want use subset of normal integration tests, which I'm writing with spring boot test libarary, so I need executable jar, which will send request to new instance and verify few base path

Comment: ` I have to verify if new application version works correctly before redirect user request to new instance` this sounds more like a test for the environment than for the application itself (which can be tested without deployment)... Furthermore I would use the real application (via spring-boot-maven-plugin) and use a differerent configuration for it `applicaton-deployment.properties`...but not a different jar otherwise it's not really testing the application...and furthermore the question. Which real tests need to be done in target environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason of my problem. It was file spring.factories with entry:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
```

When I removed file jar works correctly